# In Docusaurus, how can I hide this little icon that appears in category cards?

Tags: docusaurus

[image]I want to hide or delete this little image or icon that appears by default in a Docusaurus category card. I'm including a screenshot of it and the related CSS. How can I do this?

EDIT: It looks like it's the unicode character

```
&#x1f4c4;&#65039;
```

I don't really have access to the code that generates this HTML and for now would just like to be able to use CSS to set display:none on that unicode so that page icon doesn't appear in the cards.

[image: Card and css]